# Setting UserAgent for HttpWebRequest in Silverlight 4

Tags: silverlight-4.0, httpwebrequest

I'm using Silverlight 4 and need to set (override) the `UserAgent` for a `HttpWebRequest`. Unfortunately this is not supported.
The [platform notes in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.useragent%28v=VS.95%29.aspx) state:

> "Do not use this member when targeting Silverlight 4."

And if I try, I get a `System.NotImplementedException` with this StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.SetUserAgent(String value)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.set_UserAgent(String value)

I've tried altering the `Headers` collection directly but that returns the same error.

Is there any way to do this?

Bonus question: anyone know why this is not supported?

Comment: I am not familiar with Silverlight, and do not know why this would be protected. But.. have you tried specifying this header in the client access policy file ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx ) for your app?

Comment: @feroze the error occurs when trying to set the property so it's not an access permission issue